# jQuery get Text of parent in list

Tags: javascript, jquery, target

I have the following list

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li').click(function(e) {
    alert($(e.target).children().remove().end().text());
    alert($(e.target).siblings('span:first').text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>foo1</span>
    <span style="visibility: hidden">bar1</span>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span>foo2</span>
    <span style="visibility: hidden">bar2</span>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span>foo3</span>
    <span style="visibility: hidden">bar3</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to extract "foo1" and "bar1" at the same time in different values. The function above looks really weird. Could someone find a better approach?

Could you adjust my jQuery function please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li').click(function() {
    console.log('span #1', this.children[0].innerHTML);
    console.log('span #2', this.children[1].innerHTML);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find('span:first').text()` to get the texts with `foo`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li').click(function(e) {
    console.log($(this).find('span:first').text());
  });
});
```

```html
I have the following list $(document).ready(function() { $('li').click(function(e) { alert($(e.currentTarget).text()); }); });

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>foo1</span>
    <span style="visibility: hidden">bar1</span>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span>foo2</span>
    <span style="visibility: hidden">bar2</span>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span>foo3</span>
    <span style="visibility: hidden">bar3</span>
  </li>
</ul>

Expand snippet I would like to get only the "foo".text() of each list element clicked. With my actual approach I also receice the "bar".text() unfortunately. Could you adjust my jQuery function please? javascript jquery target shareeditcloseflag asked
6 mins ago AppRoyale 1281217
```

You can read more about `find()` [**here**](https://api.jquery.com/find/) and about `text()` [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: @AppRoyale, why the downvote. I updated my answer now. Please check it

Comment: @AppRoyale, ok, have you seen the updated answer, is it what you need?

Comment: @AppRoyale, ok. Feel free to accept the answer you think it helped you the most so people know that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find() the span, and then do the text() or html()

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li').click(function(e) {
    alert($(e.currentTarget).find('span:last-child').text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  

    <li>
    <span>foo1</span>
    <span style="visibility: hidden">bar1</span>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span>foo2</span>
    <span style="visibility: hidden">bar2</span>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span>foo3</span>
    <span style="visibility: hidden">bar3</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Modified, check it out and tell me